# Spring Data REST with Spring MVC: Adding RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration to existing DispatcherServlet

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, web.xml, spring-data-rest

I have an existing Spring MVC Application with a DispatcherServlet and an XML based configuration.

Now I would like to integrate Spring Data REST but I dont know how to do this in a clean way. I added

```
<context:component-scan>...</context:component-scan>
```

so my RestControllers are found but I fail in adding a RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration config. I tried the annotation driven approach which doesnt work

```
@Configuration
public class RestConfiguration extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {
...
}
```

and the

```
<bean class="com.mypackage.rest.RestConfiguration" />
```

approach is not working either.

I also tried the follwing in the web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>com.mypackage.rest.RestConfiguration</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Strange thing is, a method annotated with @PostConstruct is called, but non of the configure* methods.

In the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.0.0.RC1/reference/html/install-chapter.html#d5e117) for Spring Data REST is a chapter where it is explained how to add a Spring Data REST to a Spring MVC application in code. It also says

> The equivalent of the above in a standard web.xml will also work identically to this configuration if you are still in a servlet 2.5 environment.

How do you do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, in [Section 11.2](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.adding-sdr-to-spring-mvc-app) it is explained. Would have been nice to have a reference in Section 2.5 that points to Section 11.2  :-/

> In Java, this would look like:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration;

@Configuration
@Import(RepositoryRestMvConfiguration.class)
public class MyApplicationConfiguration {
  …
}
```

> In XML this would look like:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration"/>
```